# Jquery and CSS style

Tags: jquery

If I want to add an CSS style for a field in a table that has the value that is equal to the current time or greater than the current time but it is less than the value of the next field, how can I do this using Jquery?

The sample of table looks like this:

```
 -----------------------
  field |  current time
 -----------------------
    1   |    05:25
    2   |    07:30
    3   |    09:18
    4   |    10:13
    5   |    12:44
```

If the current time is 09:50 the field No.4 should have a different background color
(If the current time is 05:30 then the field No. 2 , ...)

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Why wouldn't you do that on server side?

Answer (score 1):

assuming this is ordered...

1)you should have a function ( myFunc) that can compare times and return if left argument bigger or smaller then the right.

2)you should have a function that returns the 'now' time.

3)each time span should be wrap with class **.time**

then in jQuery : each time should be wrap with class .time

```
   $(".time").each(function (){
    if (myfunc ($(this).text(),now())=='bigger')

{
 $(this).css('color','red');
return false;
}


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Cobbled this together: http://jsfiddle.net/xVDnj/1/ -- It will assign a class "past" or "future" to each table cell depending on whether the given time is before or after the current time (on the same day).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cdate = new Date();
    $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
        var $tc = $(this).find('td').eq(1)
        var tstr = $tc.text();
        var thour = tstr.split(":")[0];
        var tmin = tstr.split(":")[1];
        var tdate = new Date();
        tdate.setHours(thour,tmin);
        if (tdate-cdate < 0) { 
            $tc.addClass('past');
        } else {
            $tc.addClass('future');
        }
    });
});
```